# JSON error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: json, swift

So I am trying to call backend api to get an object of type horse, I get the object in data but when I try to decode it, it does not work. How can I fix that? You can see my Message Model and my Horse Model. I tried to find a difference between them and the json but I could not.

Message Model

```
 //
//  MessageType.swift
//  HorseStable
//
//  Created by Student on 30/12/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 smartmobile. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

enum MessageType : Int,Decodable {
         case CREATE_HORSE
          case GET_HORSE
          case UPDATE_HORSE
          case DELETE_HORSE
          case GET_HORSES_ASSIGNED_TO_USER
          case REMOVE_HORSE_FROM_USER
          case ADD_HORSE_TO_USER
      /* USERS */
      case CREATE_USER
      case GET_USER
      case UPDATE_USER
      case DELETE_USER

      /* FACILITIES */
      case CREATE_FACILITY
      case GET_FACILITY
      case UPDATE_FACILITY
      case DELETE_FACILITY

      /* STALLS */
      case CREATE_STALL
      case GET_STALL
      case UPDATE_STALL
      case DELETE_STALL

      /* POSTS */
      case CREATE_POST
      case GET_POST
          case UPDATE_POST
          case DELETE_POST

          case ADD_RESERVATION
          case REMOVE_RESERVATION

          case AUTHENTICATE
}

public class Message<T: Decodable> : Decodable {

    var type: MessageType?
    var model : T?
    init(type:MessageType,model:T) {
        self.type = type
        self.model = model
    }
```

Horse Model

```
     let id: Int?
     let name: String?
     let race: String?
     let lifeNumber : String?
     let chipNumber : String?
     let birthDate : Date?
     let gender : Gender?
     let medicalReports : [MedicalReport]?
     let owners : [User]?


 init (id:Int, name:String,race:String,lifeNumber: String, chipNumber:String, birthDate : Date, gender:Gender, medicalReports: [MedicalReport] , owners : [User]) {

      self.id = id
      self.name = name
      self.race = race
      self.lifeNumber = lifeNumber
      self.chipNumber = chipNumber
      self.birthDate = birthDate
      self.gender = gender


      self.medicalReports = medicalReports
      self.owners = owners

  }
```

Here is my JSON response:

```
{"type":"GET_HORSE","model":{"id":1,"name":"Horse2","race":"Race2","lifeNumber":"lifenumber2","chipNumber":"chipnumber2","birthDate":1579182813067,"gender":"MALE","medicalReports":[],"owners":[]}}
```

Here is the code

```
func getJSON (completion: @escaping (Message<Horse>)->()) {
        let url = "http://localhost:8083/horse/1"
    if let url = URL(string: url)
    {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

                  if error != nil || data == nil {
                      print("Client error!")
                      return
                  }
            let str = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)
            print(str)
                  do {
                   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                   print("nothing")

                    if let json = try? decoder.decode(Message<Horse>.self, from: data!) {
                       print(json)
                       print("something")
                   }

                  } catch {
                      print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                  }
              }

              task.resume()
        print("finished")
    }
```

This is the error:

```
JSON error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format
```

Comment: you should remove the if let json = try? ... 
Used instead just try ... since you are in a do catch block and you will get at least an error message

Comment: I get the same error as the one I get now

Comment: Where does your error come from and what does the error message say? That's important in order to help you.

Comment: you've shown everything except the actual error: please add it, too =)

Comment: I just added the error to the question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been asked using a different account, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787205/why-is-an-object-not-being-decoded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MessageType is an Int, but in the JSON it appears to be a string. It's possible you have a similar problem with your Gender type (which you didn't include here). Your birthDate field is a Date, but in the JSON it's an Int.

Go through your model and make sure it actually matches your JSON. Printing the `error` (rather than `error.localizedDescription`) should tell you exactly where it's having trouble. I recommend experimenting in a Playground with just the response JSON and the parser (getting rid of the networking code).